# Filter get static paths Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

How can I return only filtered paths from `getStaticPaths`?

This returns the entire posts

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/category`, config);

 const paths = data.map((post) => {
    
      return {
        params: { postId: post.id },
      };
    
  });


  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

This is what I retried

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/category`, config);

  const paths = data.filter((post) => {
     if (post.isActive) {
      return { params: { postId: post.id } }
     }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

The error message

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Additional keys were returned from `getStaticPaths` in page "/product/[packageAlias]". URL Parameters intended for this dynamic route must be nested under the `params` key,
```

Comment: You're confusing filter with map. Filter just filters out items, so your `return { params: { postId: post.id } }` is the same as just `return true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` method will return the same object formatting after filteration, so you need `map` after `filter`, You can use `flatMap` method to do both at the same time.

```
const paths = data.flatMap((post) => {
   return post.isActive ? [{ params: { postId: post.id } }] : [];
})
```